# Scroll XAML ListView line-wise instead of item-wise

Tags: c#, xaml

Is it possible to configure `ListView` so that it scrolls line by line, instead of scrolling an item at once, which is the default behavior even if the item is multiline?

Comment: I am afraid there is no such option. When I am not satisfied with the Scrolling behaviour I simply set CanContentScroll to false. This changes the bahaviour. This tells the underlying stackpanel that it is not responsible for scrolling one item at a time.

Comment: @Xeun: thanks. Quick question then: where in the XAML do I specify this attribute? Can't find it with Google...

Comment: you can maybe play around with the example code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx). Might mean that you need to change ListView to StackPanel. CanContentScroll is from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (it might be an attached property on the ListView)

Comment: Yes, Default is right. CanContentScroll is an attached property of the ScrollViewer. Therefore you can use something like.
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ... />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way, to scroll line by line. However you can try this:

By default a ListBox/ListView scrolls "intelligently" one item at a time. This behaviour is provided by a [Scrollviewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), by default the Property CanContentScroll is set to true which indicates that the items panel, f.e. a StackPanel is responsible for the scrolling and tries to scroll one item at a time.

To get close to your behaviour you simply set the Attached Property CanContentScroll to false, which enables to scroll pixel per pixel.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ... />
```

Also have a look at the link mentioned by Default which explains the [interface IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx). As he mentioned you can find tutorials [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo). However in my opinion this is way too much effort, for some simple scrolling. I normally use the easy workaround.